# Is it possible to convert from one hash to another?

Tags: md5, sha

If I give you the MD5 checksum of a string, can you generate the SHA checksum?
Or Vice Versa?

If I give you an MD5 checksum and a SHA checksum, can you tell me whether they're generated from the same source string?

(Obviously I'm excluding anything like locating the source string from a rainbow table, etc. etc.)

Answer (score 3):

No. Both are one-way hashes, so the information contained in the original source string is lost in the checksum.

Even if you do have the "original" string as you say, there will be some other data out there that when hashed, results in a collision. This is because MD5 and SHA1 are not perfect hash functions. In the case of MD5, each hash can potentially have an infinite number of collisions. Then there is no guarantee that the generated SHA checksum of the "original" string is actually what you seek.

Disclaimer: I have very little experience with the theoretical side, so you may want to verify with other resources.

Comment: apologies for necro-ing this, but I got notified that this Q had hit 1000 views.

Re-reading this answer ... the text that you've posted here don't prove it's claim.

The fact that they are both hashing functions doesn't prove that you can't derive one from the other.

If f(x) is "a one-way hash that has none of the original source string", then f(f(x)) also "a one way hash that has none of the original source string" ... but you can trivially derive the latter from the former.

Comment: Do you specifically know that those two hash algorithms cannot be derived from one another in either direction?